# Processor Upgrade in Laptop Possible?

Tags: cpu, hp-pavilion, intel-core-i5

I have HP Pavilion 15-AB031tx Laptop, which has Intel I5 5200U 5th Generation Processor, Is it possible to upgrade 5th Generation to 6th Generation?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to upgrade to a 6th gen CPU from 5th gen, as it requires a new chipset, as well as amongst other things, laptop boards and CPUs generally can't be replaced.